# keras.fit() re-initialises the weights

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning, keras

I have a model trained using `model.fit()` and used `model.save()` to save it on a physical file. Now, I have another data-set on which I want to resume training with the saved model. But, I found that every `fit()` call is been considered as a fresh training. That means, it is re-initialising the weights which was generated and saved before.

When I called `fit()` with epochs 0, then I do not see the weight reset problem. But, I definitely want to try with epochs > 0.

Am I missing something here, or is it an issue with Keras.

Keras version: 2.0.3

Thanks.

Comment: An workaround could be using train on batch

Comment: Train on batch is one of my last options. I just want to know if this is an issue in fit () or something else

Comment: you should try train on batch either way. If it works the problem is fit. If it doesn't it should be your data set or something else

Answer (score 8):

Actually - the case with calling `fit` is the following:

1. **Weights are not reset** - your model would have exactly the same weights as before calling `fit` - of course until the optimization algorithm won't change them during the first batch.
2. **Model state not reset** - this is scenario you probably came across. Model hidden states (especially in `rnn` case) are reset. This is the only thing which is changed. If you want to keep also these values (especially optimizer state is crucial in many cases) - you could use `train_on_batch` method which doesn't affect any state of model at all.
3. **Optimizer states does not reset** - Calling fit() again and again does not reset the optimizer state. Ref: https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/454#issuecomment-125644222

Answer (score 1):

Calling fit should not re-initialize the weights.

You write that you are using a new dataset - if this dataset has different statistics it could easily cause the net to rapidly lose accuracy. If this is the case, try a very small learning rate or set trainable=False for the early layers during the first few epochs.

Comment: It does re-initialise the weights. I wanted to share the code, but, it is a bit complicated as I am making GAN. Why do you think setting low learning rate or set trainable = False resolves my problem of re-initialisation problem?

Comment: You could take a look at the code on https://keras.io/applications/ which gives several examples of re-training models.

If this does not help, I'd suggest that you use train_on_batch to train on just a few examples, to determine whether weights are re-initialized or just pulled very quickly in the wrong direction. In the latter case, my suggestions about learning rate and trainable can be used.

Comment: To clarify, this proposition is not for solving problems, but to check if the weights are being reset. With trainable = False, weights should not be altered by the training and you can check is fit function changes them.